# Setting WPFToolkit AutoCompleteBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a `DataTable` named `names` in which i have 3 columns `idnr`,`name`,`surname` and i wish to add all rows from column `surname` to  WPFToolkit's `AutoCompleteBox` as `ItemsSource`.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="boxbox" Height="23"
  ItemsSource="{Binding surname}"
SelectedItem="{Binding surname, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="93,38,119,95" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set (`boxbox.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;`) or bind the `ItemsSource` property to the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` and define an `ItemTemplate` to display the value of the surname column. Also set the `ValueMemberPath` property:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="boxbox" Height="23" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding dt.DefaultView}"
                        ValueMemberPath="surname"
                        Margin="93,38,119,95">
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding surname}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

If you bind to the `ItemsSource`, the source property should return the `DefaultView` property of the `DataTable`. You also need to make sure that you set the DataContext of the `AutoCompleteBox` to an instance of the class where the source property is defined.

Comment: I have tried it like this: 

`Console.WriteLine("Output: " & dataTable.Rows(0)("surname"))
        boxbox.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView`
I have added a console line to see the output and it's: `Output: Michaels` 

AutoCompleteBox does not show anything.

Comment: Did you try to type in it? Also set the `ValueMemberPath` property.

Comment: All right, ValueMemberPath was not set. Works now! Thank you!